# Upload android project to GitHub

Tags: java, android, git, github, publish

So, I have been working on an android project, and I want to publish it on github for my teachers to be able to read it. (They don't have android studio.)
Now I have tried to use the settings in android studio, but it is not working. (Maybe the tutorials are out of date?)

So I thought I could upload the directory to GitHub online, but no. It will not let me upload that many files at once.

Do you guys know how to publish it?

Comment: Have you tried following the [GitHub Guides](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/) tutorial or any of [the other guides](https://help.github.com/categories/bootcamp/) that GitHub offers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On github,

1. In the upper-right corner of any page, click , and then click New repository.
2. Create a short, memorable name for your repository. ...
3. Optionally, add a description of your repository. ...
4. Choose between creating a public or private repository. ...
5. Select Initialize this repository with a README.
6. Copy the git repo link

then open a command line and go to your project folder and do the following:

> git init
>
> git remote add origin "paste your repo link here"

Comment: try doing this on command line in your folder:                                                            git remote remove origin     AND      
git remote add origin "repoLink"

Comment: It lets me execute both commands, but I don't see the repo updated. Even not after I execute `git commit`.

Comment: Oh I did it. I just had to `git push origin master`. Thanks for your help!